# get_posts post title permalink not working for last item in array

Tags: permalinks, get-posts

I have a custom field attatched to a post that contains the following array of post titles...

```
a:6:{i:0;s:21:"Strawberry Cheesecake";i:1;s:15:"Flapjack";i:2;s:14:"Chocolate Muffin";i:3;s:27:"Apple Turnover";i:4;s:13:"Chocolate Cookie";i:5;s:13:"Shortbread";}
```

I am then outputing those post titles, searching for the related permalink and echoing them out using....

```
<?php
$speakerarray = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cpt_food', true);
$arrlength=count($foodarray);

for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
{
$foodname = $foodarray[$x];
$posts = get_posts(array('name' => $foodname, 'post_type' => 'food'));
$post = $posts[0];
$permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
echo '<a href="';
echo $permalink;
echo '">';
echo $foodname;
echo '</a>';
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Everything works fine apart from the last result, I have duplicated the issue with numerous items in the array etc.. and its always the last one that fails.  It returns the permalink for the page I am currently on instead.

Can anyone see why?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `foreach` loop instead, as the count index isn't the best way to walk over an array.

```
<?php
$speakerarray = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cpt_food', true);
foreach($speakerarray as $foodname) :
    $posts = get_posts(array('name' => $foodname, 'post_type' => 'food'));
    $post = $posts[0];
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '>' . $foodname . '</a><br>';
endforeach;
?>
```

I used a online tool for unserialize your data and it returned an error ?